# Outlook HTML Email has extra space

Tags: html, css

I am hoping someone can please help me.

I built this email signature using HTML and in-line css. It looks fine on most mailers and browsers, but with outlook I get this space between tables (on the right). I have no idea what I am doing wrong. As soon as I add a table to the left side then spaces pop up everywhere. Please help!

```html
<table width="600" height="150"border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td width="255" height="150">
    
        <table width="255" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="255" style = "padding:0 30px 7.8px 25px;"><img src = "https://nuoutline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/email_signature_logo.jpg">
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="255" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="20"></td>
                <td width="auto" style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"></td>
                <td width="25"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="255" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="20" style = "padding-top:6.4px;"></td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding-top:6.4px; text-align:center; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8px; color: #000; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .7">
                    CARBON | CONSERVATION | CLIMATE | COMMUNITY</td>
                <td width="27" style = "padding-top:6.4px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="345" height="150">
        <table width="345" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="345" style="font-family: Calibri;font-size:22px;color:#1C407B;font-weight: normal;">Person Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="345" style="padding-top: 2px; font-family: Calibri;font-size:13px;color:#5C5C5C;font-weight: normal;">
                    Editor and Communication Specialist
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="334" style = "padding-top:6.5px; border-bottom: 3px solid #1C407B;"></td>
                <td width="11" style = "padding-top:6.5px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="345" border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #5C5C5C; font-weight: 400;text-align: left;">18 Gerrie Avenue
                </td>
                <td width="36" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #1C407B; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">|
                </td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #5C5C5C; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">Tokai
                </td>
                <td width="36" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #1C407B; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">|
                </td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #5C5C5C; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">Cape Town
                </td>
                <td width="36" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #1C407B; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">|
                </td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #5C5C5C; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;">South Africa
                </td>
                <td width="11" style = "padding-top:6.5px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px; color: #5C5C5C; font-weight: 400;text-align: center;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="345" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding:5px 0 0 0;">
                    <a style="font-family: Calibri;font-size:11px;text-decoration: none;color: #5C5C5C;font-weight: normal;" href="tel:+2721 7120282"><span style = "color:#1C407B; font-weight: bold;">t:</span> Phone Number</a>
                </td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding:5px 0 0 0;">
                    <a style="padding-left:8px; font-family: Calibri;font-size:11px;text-decoration: none;color: #5C5C5C;font-weight: normal;" href="mailto:willemien.calitz@c4es.co.za"><span style = "color:#1C407B; font-weight: bold;">e:</span> Email</a>
                </td>
                <td width="auto" style = "padding:5px 0 0 0;">
                    <a style="padding-left:8px; font-family: Calibri;font-size:11px;text-decoration: none;color: #5C5C5C;font-weight: normal;" href="https://c4es.co.za/"><span style = "color:#1C407B; font-weight: bold;">w:</span> www.c4es.co.za</a>
                </td>
                <td width="11" style = "padding:5px 0 0 0;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you can add margin and padding of 0px in the body tag

Comment: could you please provide an image of the issue as it appears in outlook

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up getting someone else to build it for me, so I am not sure exactly what he did to fix the issue, but it was probably something small and easy...appreciate the help though!